# Is there a formula for $\{1,2b,3b^2-a^2,4b^3-4a^2b,\ldots\}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$n_1=1$$
$$n_2=2b$$
$$n_3=3b^2-a^2$$
$$n_4=4b^3-4a^2b$$
$$n_5=5b^4-10a^2b^2+a^4$$
$$n_6=6b^5-20a^2b^3+6a^4b$$
$$n_7=7b^6-35a^2b^4+21a^4b^2-a^6$$
$$n_i=?$$

I can give more terms if it helps.

Comment: Those look like (every other) binomial coefficient. Can you take it form here?

Comment: What method do you use to produce more terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like
$$n_k=\frac{(b+ai)^k-
(b-ai)^k}{2ai} $$

Comment: Thank you so much!